# Как определить, что сообщение по TCP полностью получено?

Tags: сеть, tcp, tcp-ip, сетевое-программирование

Из-за того, что TCP фрагментирует отправляемые пакеты, а так же из-за того, что он является потоковым протоколом, нет гарантии, что вызов в духе

```
read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)
```

вернувший N < MAXLINE прочитаных байт, получит все сообщение, длина которого может быть больше N.
Какими способами можно проверить, что сообщение получено полностью?

Comment: только средствами своего протокола, который работает поверх TCP. например передавать длину сообщения в начале. Или понимать конец сообщения по каким либо завершающим байтам

Comment: например HTTP, которым ты передашь структурированный JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Средствами TCP никак не получится проверить, все ли данные были приняты. Поэтому следует использовать дополнительные соглашения (протоколы более высокого уровня), позволяющие однозначно определить конец данных.

Например, в таких случаях применяют следующие подходы:

1. Передача завершающего байта или байтовой последовательности (например `\0` при передаче строк в C/C++)
2. Передача стартового и завершающего последовательностей – модификация первого подхода, используемая для беспрерывного потока данных (чтобы случайно не принять окончание предыдущей порции данных за начало новой)
3. Передача в начале последовательности её длины
4. Комбинации вышеперечисленного

Из реальных примеров, если память мне не изменяет, в HTTP используется двойной перевод строки (CRLF CRLF) для отделения заголовков от данных. Таким образом, получив такую последовательность, можно быть уверенным, что порция данных, содержащая заголовки, принята полностью.